# Sum and product of two irrational numbers - a logical proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

going through elementary number theory and I came across two questions of the same nature.

Prove or disprove

1. Sum of two irrational numbers is an irrational},
2. Product of two irrational numbers is an irrational number.

I can prove that with examples, sure, like the pairs $(1 + \sqrt{2}), (-\sqrt{2})$ and $(1 + \sqrt{2}), (1 - \sqrt{2})$.

But how do I prove this mathematically through logic instead of examples? I could think of a prove where either the sum of both or sum of one inversed is rational but not both. But proving each on their own (and the product version), couldn't.

Any help/guidance would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: prove what?  your counterexamples show that both claims are false (in general).  To be thorough, you should also find examples where the claims are true (not difficult).

Comment: Right ..but I'm thinking outside of using examples. Is that possible? Similar way of proving mathematically the sum of two rationals is rational.

Comment: As a side note I'm back to studying after a very long time, by myself and I get confused or unsure of what is *the right way* - espcially for proofs. It is possible that just showing counterexamples are enough, or that there is no proof of the nature I'm looking for, for some reason. But I don't know that :) I'd love if someone can explain that.

Comment: But again, to prove what?  If you want to show that there exist two irrationals $\alpha, \beta $ such that their sum (or product if you prefer) is irrational, you can do that by counting arguments.  Seems a bit artificial, though, since examples are so easily found.

Comment: > But again, to prove what?
The same thing, just without using counterexamples.

Comment: You cannot prove something in general wrong. You can add assumptions wich let you do this.

Comment: Again, what do you want to prove?  Your counterexamples show that both of the claims are false, you you can't prove them.

Comment: A counterexample is a perfectly "logical" way of proving that a statement of the form "for every $X$, $Y$" is false.

Comment: To stress:  a single counterexample is all it takes to show that a claim is false.

Comment: @debdutdeb It would help if you gave some motivation for wanting to avoid counterexamples.  Are you trying to avoid repeating a mistake that involved providing a counterexample rather than a general argument?  Or is it purely an aesthetic difference?

Comment: A COUNTEREXAMPL, proving that a statement is NOT true is perfectly good logic!

Comment: If you mean "nontrivial" examples , they will be hard to find. One of $e+\pi$ or $e\cdot \pi$ could be an example although it is very unlikely because they are not known to be irrational. If you just want to disprove such a statement , you only need to find a single counterexample. All further efforts are wasted. Of course you can try to characterize WHEN this statement fails , but as stated this is extremely difficult , if possible at all.

Answer (score -1):

Well, maybe this is the sort of thing you're looking for.  For any irrational number $x$ and any rational $r$, there is an irrational number $y$ such that $x+y = r$ (namely $y = r-x$), and (if $r \ne 0$) an irrational $z$ such that $xz = r$ (namely $r/x$).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).